# ¿Cómo hacer un inner join en linq?

Tags: linq, asp.net-web-api, join

Tengo una api que me devuelve la tabla de los productos vendidos en su detalle, pero necesito hacer un 'inner join' con la finalidad de obtener el nombre de cada producto que se ha vendido.

Pero al código mostrado aquí debajo realmente no encuentro la forma de como agregarle la tabla de productos para poder lograr visualizar el nombre de cada item.

Gracias por la ayuda.

```
    [Route("api/PedidosDetalle/{PedCodigo}/{RepCodigo}")]

    public List<PedidosDetalle> Get(int PedCodigo, string RepCodigo)
    {

        using (ModelApi entidad = new ModelApi())

        {

            return entidad.PedidosDetalles.Where(e=> e.RepCodigo == RepCodigo && e.PedCodigo == PedCodigo).ToList();
        }

    }
```

Intenté con el siguiente código:

```
  [Route("api/PedidosDetalle/{PedCodigo}/{RepCodigo}")]
        public List<PedidosDetalle> Get(int PedCodigo, string RepCodigo)
        {
            using (ModelApi entidad = new ModelApi())
            {
                var q = (from s in entidad.Productos
                         join t in entidad.PedidosDetalles on s.ProCodigo equals t.ProCodigo

                         where t.RepCodigo == RepCodigo &&  t.PedCodigo == PedCodigo

                         select new
                         {
                             s.ProDescripcion

                         });

                return q.ToList();
            }
```

Pero me está dando el error que desglosa la imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
        }
```

Comment: Agrega la declaracions de  las dos entidades que haran el join

Comment: Ese es el punto que no se como realizarlo por eso estoy buscando ayuda.

Comment: Solo era la definicion de clases involucradas para indicar como podrias hacer el query

Answer (score 1):

así

```
var innerJoinQuery =
    from category in categories
    join prod in products on category.ID equals prod.CategoryID
    select new { ProductName = prod.Name, Category = category.Name };
```

aca te dejo mas [info](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause)

Answer (score 0):

Tu error es porque tu método devuelve un `List<Pedidos>` y la consulta devuelve un nuevo objeto que no es del modelo Pedidos. Debes convertir tu objeto nuevo de la consulta a `List<Pedidos>`. Fácilmente podrías recorrer con un foreach y rellenar tu `List<Pedidos>`.